# What is a model reference set on app.set()?

Tags: node.js, express, sequelize.js

I see an node application in which the the index.js (model loader) file has the following structure:

```
"use strict";

var fs        = require("fs");
var path      = require("path");
var Sequelize = require("sequelize");
var env       = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";
var config    = require(__dirname + '/../../../config/db.json')[env];
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
var db        = {};

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(function(file) {
    return (file.indexOf(".") !== 0)
      && (file !== "index.js");
  })
  .forEach(function(file) {
    var model = sequelize["import"](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

// Link models according associations
//
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ("associate" in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

// Add scopes
//
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ('loadScope' in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].loadScope(db);
  }
});

// Link models based on associations that are based on scopes
//
Object.keys(db).forEach(function(modelName) {
  if ('scopeAssociate' in db[modelName]) {
    db[modelName].scopeAssociate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

And then in the main app.js file i see this export of the db being used like so:-

```
// Add single reference to the model into application object
// and reuse it whenever an access to DB is needed
app.set('db_model', require('./lib/model/db'));
```

In the above line i understand that basically a reference of the db is being set for the entire app. this seems to me as an unusual pattern but it made me curious. I wanted to know what exactly is the advantage of **setting** a model reference like above ? does it help a great deal ? Does it **prevent** certain bad patterns ? I really want to know.

**Additional information :**

I see the above gets used like so later on in controllers

```
const model = req.app.get('db_model');

  req.user.getCompany({
    scope : ['with_active_users'],
  })
  .then(company => {

    let attributes = get_and_validate_department({
      req             : req,
      suffix          : 'new',
      company         : company,
      department_name : 'New department'
    });

    if ( req.session.flash_has_errors() ) {
      return Promise.resolve(1);
    }

    attributes.companyId = company.id;

    return model.Department.create(attributes);
  })
```

Also a reference [**HERE**](https://github.com/timeoff-management/timeoff-management-application/blob/244a10ef39ad4863edf94009e064cb125cd4cbbb/lib/model/db/index.js) to the main index.js model file. To summerise my question what exactly is the use of using the app.set() for setting a reference to the model ? or is it just a fancy way of doing things ?

Comment: I don't see any benefits of `const model = req.app.get('db_model');` against `require('./lib/model/db')` because NodeJs initializes this module only once and will always return the same `db`.

Comment: Until you will need to switch several `db` modules dynamically at runtime which is not your case as I see.

Comment: @Anatoly thanks for the insight , btw , can you give me an example of multiple `db`modules as i can't quite visualize the scenario , if possible pls add it in an answer :) do you mean model references to multiple db's ?

Comment: Yes, something like model references to different DBs. Maybe in the case when it's needed to sync two DBs with the same or similar structure